# Python: numerical sorting in QTableWidget

Tags: python, sorting, pyqt, qtablewidget

I need first column of my QTableWidget to be populated as: Row: 1, Row: 2...Row: 100 ,
but sorting doesn't work as expected (numerically).
Sorting works fine with this code, but I don't get expected text:

```
for i in range(0, self.rows):
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, "Row: %s" %(i) )
    item.setData(Qt.EditRole, i)
    self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(i, 0, item)
```

I get: 1,2,3,4... instead of  Row: 1, Row: 2, Row: 3...
I expected that EditRole will be used for editing purposes (for numerical sorting, which works fine) but I also expected that text will be shown because it was set with DisplayRole.
Can I do this that way somehow or writing function for purposes of sorting is the only way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am still interested why DisplayRole and EditRole doesn't do what I've expected, but I've solved the problem like this:

```
class MyTableWidgetItem(QtGui.QTableWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, text, sortKey):
            QtGui.QTableWidgetItem.__init__(self, text, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem.UserType)
            self.sortKey = sortKey

    #Qt uses a simple < check for sorting items, override this to use the sortKey
    def __lt__(self, other):
            return self.sortKey < other.sortKey
```

... populating table:

```
for i in range(0, self.rows):
    item = MyTableWidgetItem("Row: %s" %(i), i)
    self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(i, 1, item)
```

Answer (score 7):

For `QTableWidgetItem`, the `Qt.DisplayRole` and `Qt.EditRole` are treated the same.

This means that, in the code:

```
item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, "Row: %s" %(i) )
item.setData(Qt.EditRole, i)
```

the second line will simply overwrite the data set in the first line. So, effectively, there is no separate `EditRole` (unless the `data` and `setData` functions are reimplemented).

The standard way to alter the sort behaviour is to reimplement the less-than operator for `QTableWidgetItem` (which, by default, is hard-coded to use the `DisplayRole` data for sorting).

The following subclass will reproduce what Qt would normally do for numerical sorting:

```
class TableWidgetItem(QtGui.QTableWidgetItem):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return (self.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole).toLongLong() <
                other.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole).toLongLong())
```